# Laravel - Show custom error in validation field

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to show a custom error in validation field, but it always shows the default message.

This is my controller:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'nombre.required' => 'Completá el nombre',
    ];
}
```

This is my blade template code:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: can you add your rules to the question?

Comment: @MateusJunges what you mean with "my rules"?

Comment: It seems to be a laravel form request. It must have a `rules` method. Can you add it to the question?